# Why is Laplace Transform used for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image]

This part is taken from differential equations with applications and historical George simmons.

According to the given information , there are another integral transformation.I wonder why is the Laplace transform ($a=0 , b=\infty , K(p,x)=e^{-px}$) begin used for solving ODEs.Are there any advantages or other particular reasons for using this combination ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laplace transform is useful because

1. it transforms an ODE into an algebraic equation in the transformed variable (or a PDE into an ODE), and
2. it includes the initial conditions as part of the algebraic equation.

The usefulness of this LT of course depends on the ability to find the inverse transform of the solution to the algebraic equation. In general, this requires the evaluation of a complex integral.  However, for those not versed in complex integration methods, there are tables from which one may simply write down the inverse.  Thus, the LT provides a simple means of solving an ODE using algebra.

No better way to understand this than to provide a specific example.  Let's solve

$$f''(t) + 4 f'(t) + 3 f(t) = t \sin{t}$$
$$f(0) = 0 \quad f'(0) = 1$$

The LT of the LHS of the equation is

$$s^2 F(s) - 1 + 4 s F(s) + 3F(s) $$

The LT of the RHS is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t \sin{t}\; e^{-s t} = \operatorname{Im}{\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t \, e^{-(s-i) t}} = \operatorname{Im}{\left [\frac1{(s-i)^2}\right ]} = \frac{2 s}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

We need only solve a simple algebraic equation to find $F(s)$:

$$F(s) = \frac{(s^2+1)^2+2 s}{(s^2+1)^2 (s+3)(s+1)} $$

We may then use tables or the residue theorem to find the inverse:

$$f(t) = \frac14 e^{-t} - \frac{47}{100} e^{-3 t} + \frac{1}{50} [(5 t+2) \sin{t} +(11-10 t) \cos{t}]$$

Comment: So , İf I can find a another kernel with a boundary which provides that I can transform the equation and then do inverse transformation ,can I use for solving ODEs  ? Or Does it give me the true result ?

Comment: I mean I try to understand that can I use any kernel with boundary that allows me to calculate the solution to the ODEs with same strategy.Are there any restrictions for transformations ?

Comment: @Leth: What you need to understand is that a transform is useless unless you can find the inverse.  That's why the LT is useful - because finding the inverse is a well-defined operation.  This is not true of arbitrarily-defined kernels.

Comment: I assume that I can find the inverse .Then can I use ?

Comment: @Leth: Without seeing what you mean, I cannot answer.  There are precious few transforms I know of that have easily-computable inverses, so if you have one, that's pretty major.  Also, you need a simple way to incorporate initial/boundary conditions.  If you can satisfy that, and the transform of the ODE is at least a simpler ODE, if not an algebraic eq'n, then all the power to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact many other integral transforms with specific kernels. The truth is that there is virtually no advantage of using the Laplace transform to solve differential equations, in comparison to other methods. Indeed, the method requires that you are able to compute explicitly the Laplace transform of any functions that are involved, which is really too much to hope for. Moreover, the transform has no use in the study of arbitrary perturbations, say to understand whether sufficiently small perturbations don't change the type of stability of an equilibrium point. Overall, in the context of solving differential equations, it is not much to say that the transform is of no use.